# Side scrolling game in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Does anyone have advice on creating a side-scrolling action game in Ruby?

I am particularly looking for libraries, tools, or guides. I've built a terminal text-based game however now I'd like to involve graphics and possibly run the game outside of terminal.

It's important to me that it be in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about libgosu?

http://www.libgosu.org/

"Gosu is a 2D game development library for the Ruby and C++ programming languages, available for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux. It has been in development since 2001."

"Ruby/Gosu integrates well:

```
 gem install gosu
```

complete with examples, precompiled for Windows & OS X"

Answer (score 2):

A very nice toolkit for making 2D graphics is SDL there are ruby bindings available at
[http://www.kmc.gr.jp/~ohai/rubysdl.en.html](http://www.kmc.gr.jp/%7Eohai/rubysdl.en.html)

oreilly net has a very nice article about writing games with ruby  here
https://web.archive.org/web/20170813235228/http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/2007/12/04/creating-games-in-ruby.html

If jruby is ok for you, you can use various java libries for the gfx part like java2D or
processing ( http://www.rubyinside.com/using-the-processing-graphics-system-from-ruby-780.html )